# Template classes with specialised constructors

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, metaprogramming

Consider the following contrived example of a templated array definition:

```
template <typename t, unsigned int n> class TBase
{
protected:
    t m_Data[n];

    //...
};

template <typename t, unsigned int n> class TDerived : public TBase<t, n>
{
    TDerived()
    {
    }
};
```

I can specialize this type to provide a non-default constructor for an array of length 2 as follows:

```
template <typename t> class TDerived<t, 2> : public TBase<t, 2>
{
public:
    TDerived(const t& x0, const t& x1)
    {
        m_Data[0] = x0;
        m_Data[1] = x1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    TDerived<float, 2> Array2D_A(2.0f, 3.0f); //uses specialised constructor
    TDerived<float, 3> Array3D_A;             //uses default constructor

    return 0;
}
```

Is there some other way I can create a class that has different constructor options constrained against template parameters at compile-time without the requirement for a complete class specialisation for each variation?

In other words, is there some way I can have specialised constructors in the `TBase` class without the need for the intermediary step of creating `TDerived` whilst preserving the functionality of `TBase`?

Comment: What compiler and version are you using, does it have C++0x support?

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas I switch between MSVC 2008/2010 so both yes and no.

Comment: Why not just put in all the constructors? They won't be instantiated unless they are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think deriving your class from a base class is not relevant to the question here, that's a mere implementation detail. What you really seem to be after is if there's a way to partially specialize member functions, like the constructor. Do you want something like this?

```
template <typename T, int N> class Foo
{
    Foo(); // general
    template <typename U> Foo<U, 2>(); // specialized, NOT REAL CODE
};
```

This doesn't work. You always have to specialize the entire class. The reason is simple: You have to know the full type of the class first *before* you even know which member functions exist. Consider the following simple situation:

```
template <typename  T> class Bar
{
  void somefunction(const T&);
};

template <> class Bar<int>
{
  double baz(char, int);
};
```

Now `Bar<T>::somefunction()` depends on `T`, but the function only *exists* when `T` is not `int`, because `Bar<int>` is an entirely different class.

Or consider even another specialization `template <> class Bar<double> : public Zip {};` -- even the polymorphic nature of a class can be entirely different in a specialization!

So the only way you can provide <s>specializations</s> new declarations of members, including constructors, is by specializing the entire class. (You *can* specialize the *definition* of existing functions, see @Alf's answer.)

Comment: -1 "the only way you can provide specializations of members, including constructors, is by specializing the entire class." is incorrect.

Comment: @Alf: Hm, OK, if you have member templates, you can specialize those individually. But I meant "specialize members on the class parameters". How to best say that?

Comment: you can specialize members. E.g. see my answer. :-)

Comment: I see, but that's different, because you're not changing the signature, so you're specializing the *definition*. In my example, you couldn't specialize `template<> Bar<int>::somefunction(const int&)`, because it doesn't exist. This should be made precise...

Comment: @Alf: I appreciate very much getting this right! It's a very important part of C++.

Comment: I agree, the derivation from a base class is not really relevant, other than to indicate that there is a common base for shared functionality between all specialisations. I was not aware that specialising a class creates an entirely new class, so thank you for that! Do you happen to know why specialisation of the definition of an existing method is limited to only accept full specialisations and not partial specialisation (i.e. why is partial specialisation allowed only on class types but not on their members)?

Comment: @Munro: Functions in general cannot be partially specialized, only fully. It's a general limitation of the language (I don't know if there's a reason).

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two options I see for this:

- Use a variadic function for construction (ie. "..." notation), you can use the value n inside that function to get your arguments from the stack. However, the compiler will not check at compile time if the user provides the correct number of arguments.
- Use some serious template magic to allow a call chaning initialization, that would look like this: `vector(2.0f)(3.0f)`. You can actually build something that at least ensures the user does not provide too many arguments here. However tha mechanism is a little more involved, I can assemble an example if you want.

Comment: I don't want to go near variadic arguments at all if I can help it! I'm intrigued as to what you mean by call chaining initialization using template wizardry though...

Comment: It goes rhoughly like this: Create a templated class that will accept the number of elements in the vector as template parameter N. However, let this class only hold one of these elements, and let it derive from a class that holds one less element. Specialize for N=1 element to stop the inheritance chain. Define a method like this: `Vector<N-1>& operator()(double e) { element=e; return (Vector<N-1>&)*this; }`, in the specialization for N=1, have this return void or something else that does not define operator().

Answer (score 1):

You can always specialize a member, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

template< class Type >
struct Foo
{
    void bar() const
    { printf( "Single's bar.\n" ); }
};

template<>
void Foo< double >::bar() const
{ printf( "double's bar.\n" ); }

int main()
{
    Foo<int>().bar();
    Foo<double>().bar();
}
```

But you want effectively different signatures, so it's not directly a case of specializing a member.

One way forward is then to declare a constructor with a single argument, of a type dependent on the template parameters.

Then you can specialize that, as you want.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: One important note. in OP's question there are 2 template parameters, so we need to know both the parameters to spcialize it. I have documented that in my answer (may be MSVC supports partial specialization).

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach @iammilind Whilst this is a potential solution, ideally I would like to have a partial specialisation on the constructor -- for example, by specifying a length but not a type `TBase(const t& x0){}`, with the partial specialisation as follows `template <typename t>  TBase<t, 1>::TBase (const t& x0)` -- but it would appear that this is not possible.

Comment: @Munro, for function, partial specialization is not allowed by standard. So, you can give a try for different types as, I mentioned in my answer (if there are not so many potential types).

Answer (score 1):

Since constructor is a function, you need to fully specialize the containing class to address your specific problem. No way out.

However, functions cannot be partially specialized (in all compilers). So suppose if you know that you need `n = 2` when `t = int or double` then following is one alternative.

```
template<>
TDerived<int,2>::TDerived()
{
  //...
}
template<>
TDerived<double,2>::TDerived()
{
  //...
}
```

and so on.

[Note: If you use MSVC, then I think it supports partial specialization; in that case you can try:

```
template<typename t>
TDerived<t,2>::TDerived()
{
  //...
}
```

though, I am not sure enough for that.]

Comment: If you take another look at my original question, I'm already using partial template specialisation to create my specialised constructor so I'm not quite sure what you are suggesting beyond what was already there. I am using MSVC.

Comment: Sorry, I've reread your post and I think I initially misinterpreted. You are correct, I can specialise the constructor, but partial specialisation of constructors (or member functions for that matter) are apparently not allowed. I was not aware of that!

Comment: @Munro, you are using partial specialization for full `class`. I am saying that if you just want to have constructor for `<t,2>` then you can simply specialize the constructor. You don't have to specialize full class. In MSVC, I know that they allow partial specialization of methods; if that's not possible then you can choose what I suggest in my main answer where you know that `t` is going to be `int`,`double`,... then specialize `<int,2>`, `<double,2>`.

Answer (score 0):

You could give the most common definitions in the non-specialized class and `static_assert` (BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT for non C++0x) on the array length. This could be considered a hack but is a simple solution to your problem and safe.

```
template<typename T, unsigned int n>
struct Foo {
  Foo(const T& x) { static_assert(n == 1, "Mooh!"); }
  Foo(const T& x1, const T& x2) { static_assert(n == 2, "Mooh!"); }
};
```

The "evil" way would be variadic arguments.

```
template<typename T, unsigned int n>
struct Foo {
  Foo(...) { 
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, n);
    for(int j=0; j < n; ++j)
      bork[j] = va_arg(ap, T);
    va_end(ap);
  }
};
```

Then there is also C++0x and the good old `make_something` trick which is more difficult then one would think.

```
template<typename... T, unsigned int n>
Foo<T, n> make_foo(T&&...) {
  // figure out the common_type of the argument list
  // to our Foo object with setters or as a friend straight to the internals
  Foo< std::common_type< T... >::type, sizeof(T) > foo;
  // recursive magic to pick the list apart and assign 
  // ...
  return foo;
}
```

Comment: Your simple solution was how I originally started (albeit with a non-static assert, initially I had a runtime check), that was what started me down the route to looking for alternatives. I'm not even going to go near your "evil" route! Your c++0x variadic template solution looks interesting although I'm unfamiliar with the syntax (I've not delved into the mysteries and magic of c++0x as of yet).

Comment: @Munro: My `make_something` would indeed require some tweaking and the `common_type` part is a little brittle. I can fiddle a Boost.PreProcessor macro together to make the easy way less verbose.